# Getting event object from setting event via a string

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a div with an onclick event handler like

```
element.innerHTML = '<div onclick="somefunction(e, 10)"></div>';
```

where e would be the event object and 10 is some other random argument. I can't seem to find a way to do this. Is it possible?

Note that I do not want to create and then append the child to the parent element separately.

Comment: No. Quit those dirty in-line javascript hacks.

Comment: Yes (see answers). Do what is best for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

For inline handlers like that you should be able to pass the `event` object directly if you spell it out in full rather than `e` (in your actual function definition you can call the corresponding parameter anything you like):

```
element.innerHTML = '<div onclick="somefunction(event, 10)"></div>';
```

For other event registration techniques there are other ways to get access to the event object, but inline is kind of a special case that should be the same in all browsers.

For more detail see this page: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html

Comment: It works because in browsers conforming to Netscape's event model (such as Mozilla and Firefox), *event* resolves to the handler's event object. In other browsers (like IE) *event* resolves to the global *window.event* object, which is essentially the same thing.